# Getting ValueError while storing string dataset in HDF5 format

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I am using HFD5 format to store the data about an object which contains attribute like description, id, name and various others. I am using pandas.HDFStore.append function to store my data(pandas DataFrame object) in a tabular format. I cannot know the length of the description field in advance and it results in ValueError while storing the object which exceeds the min_itemsize value.

Currently, the parameters of the functions are set to:

format='table'

append=True

min_itemsize=1000

data_columns=True.

The exact Error is:

ValueError: Trying to store a string with len [1620] in [description] column but
this column has a limit of [1000]!
Consider using min_itemsize to preset the sizes on these columns

Can we dynamically change(increase/decrease) the min_itemsize value or is there any other way to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Why cant you set `min_itemsize` to the `max` of the `lengths` of the description you get in each batch?

Comment: I can do that only for the first time. As I am appending the batches to the same key, I cannot reset the min_itemsize value to the max of the length of the description of the next batch. This too leads to the same error.